# Calculate minimum set of values which satisfies a conditional expression?

Tags: conditional-statements

I have a conditional expression:

```
if( (x > 0) && (x < 10) || (x == -2))
```

What I'm doing currently whenever there is a ">" symbol I'm just adding a value and in case of "<" symbol I'm subtracting a value.

So, in this case the `x` values are: `1, 9, -2`. But, I want here is minimum number of values.

As per my logic: `{1, 9, -2}`
Minimum set = `{1,-2}`

Comment: Why is your minimum set not `{1}`? `1` passes the condition and `{1}` is smaller than `{1,-2}`.

Comment: a python solution: print `set(([x for x in range(-2, 10) if x > 0 and x < 10 or x == -2])[0:2])`

Comment: @melpomene: I want to cover all the expression inside the conditional expression. So it's 1 and -2.